# How to import data from a specific column in multiple Spreadsheets into one Spreadsheet using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import

I am not into the programming at all so I am requesting your help, guys).
I have a group project with my students. Each of them got their own working template in spreadsheet with individual data. I need to work with all that data they collect each day, merged in one place. So I created a formula below:

```js
=query({
    importrange("spreadsheetSheetId1","sheetName!sheetRange");
    importrange("spreadsheetSheetId2","sheetName!sheetRange");
    importrange("spreadsheetSheetId3","sheetName!sheetRange");
    importrange("spreadsheetSheetId4","sheetName!sheetRange");
    importrange("spreadsheetSheetIdn","sheetName!sheetRange")
    },"Select * Where Col2 is not NULL")
```

But there is a problem: for now I already have 60 spreadsheets and it makes my file very slow. Plus I receive errors when imports getting updated and I am unable to work with the whole collected data.

Can you help me create a script that will do the same work as my query formula and it will be working 2 times per day by schedule?

Comment: I'd need to know more about what you require in order to give you a reasonable answer,but basically you can copy a sheet from one spreadsheet to another and then once you have all of the sheets in one spreadsheet you can merge them altogether.  Having said that i still don't really know anything about your project  so it's difficult to give you a precise answer.  I'm kind of wondering though why you didn't think about this before you assigned the project.

Comment: It'll take me some time to write the full solution but essentially what you want to do is have a master "tracker" spreadsheet/sheet. In it you'll put the file IDs for each student's spreadsheet -- one on each row. Then you'll have a script that will go through each row, open the spreadsheet, pull in data, and write it back to the master tracker. Does that make sense? I do this now for a similar challenge. It works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you desire by using [Apps Scripts time-based triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

However, you still have to code a function to get your student data ranges; that will run when the trigger is executed.

## One example:

1. [Create a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) from the spreadsheet where you gather all the fetched data ("Control Spreadsheet" or "CS" for short).
2. You must supply student's spreadsheet Id's or names to get each of them. (eg. a sheet where map students to their data sheets)
3. You also want a sheet to gather all the data in your CS. (I named it, pause!, drumroll, "WorkSheet!").
4. Write a function that fetches data and pastes it in your WorkSheet. Do it for every spreadsheet on the list.

**eg.**

```js
function getStudentsData(){
  
  // Get control spreadsheet
  var controlSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  
  // Activate work sheet
  var teacherWorkSheet = controlSS.getSheetByName('WorkSheet').activate();
  
  // Remove old data in work sheet
  prepWorkSheet(teacherWorkSheet);
  
  // Fetch data from every student's sheet
  /* 
  * For this example the students sheets are in the same control spreadsheet,
  * and are named "Student1,Student2,..." and so on. In your case, supply a 
  * list of student spreadsheets as per your requirements.
  */
  var list_length = 4; // The length of your students spreadsheets array (~ 60).
  var startRow = 1;  // Omit headers in destination
  
  for (var i = 1; i < list_length; i++){
    
    // Get student sheet
    var studentSheet = controlSS.getSheetByName('Student'+i);
    
    // Get Student's data range
    var studentDataRange = studentSheet.getDataRange();
    
    // Omit headers in student's data
    studentDataRange = studentDataRange.offset(1, 0, studentDataRange.getLastRow()-1);
    
    // Copy the values  and paste them to the control spreadsheet 
    studentDataRange.copyValuesToRange(teacherWorkSheet,1,
                                       studentDataRange.getLastColumn(), 
                                       startRow, 
                                       startRow + studentDataRange.getLastRow());
    
    // Assign new starting row for pasting data
    startRow = teacherWorkSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1; 
  }
}

function prepWorkSheet(sheet){
  
  // Wipe destination sheet for example...
  sheet.getDataRange().deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}
```

5. [Manually add a time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to execute `getStudentData()` every 12 hours (tailor to your needs).
6. Enjoy programming ;)

Comment: "From what I could extract from your question, all of the student's data comes from *Col2*"
Not exactly, I mean that I need to get a filtred import, where I can get filled data projects, range that I use for now is A2:AN

Comment: You can use the [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension) to tailor the data range to your needs after you fetch it.